# How do I add numbers with decimal places

Tags: javascript, precision

I am trying to create a form that adds up numbers to two decmial points.  I.e. be able to add up 5.5 with 105.67 with 12.54 and get: 123.71

Here is as far as I've got, but when I try adding .toFixed(2) it either just does the inputs and not the total...

I'm very new to Javascript so just finding way at mo

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Vicky1984/Lpwcuyb5/d

Here is code I'm using;

```
function findTotal() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
  var tot = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
      tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
   }
  document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
 }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: parseFloat() not parseInt()

Answer (score 2):

`parseFloat()` will return floating point numbers. ex. 1, 0, -2, 3.3, 505.1236

`parseInt()` will return whole number integers ex. -1, 0, 1, 2, -59635

Use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

BTW, each id must be unique, so the second input is now `qty2`

[**<kbd>FIDDLE</kbd>**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/g3ftfh0q/1/)

**SNIPPET**

```js
function findTotal() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
  var tot = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseFloat(arr[i].value))
      tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">

  <div class="row header">
    <div class="cell">
      Take Home Pay
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      Amount Per Month
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      Salary
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <input placeholder="0.00" onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty1" />
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      Overtime
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <input placeholder="0.00" onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2" />
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row total-row">
    <div class="cell">
      Total Take Home Pay
    </div>
    <div class="cell" data-label="Monthly Income">
      <input placeholder="0.00" type="text" name="total" id="total" />

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You are a genius!!  Thank you sooo much! That is awesome :) :)

Comment: apologies won't let me click on the 'tick' as I haven't got enough ticks or something. but def a tick :)

Comment: @Vicky12345 No worries, you can come back when you have full `ticking powers` I've added an extra demo that dynamically generates the rows and cells of the table as it populates it with data.

Comment: OOPs. My bad, wrong question. Sorry the update was for another question. 